# complexity of the function T(N)=T(n/2)+2^n

Tags: algorithm, master-theorem

I am a student taking the algorithm course at university. I know how to apply a few recursive techniques to find the running cost of simpler functions but the `2^n` in this question is causing me trouble. Here is what I have tried applying master theorem

`a=1`, `b=2` `n^log2(1)= n^0.65`

This leads to `n^0=1` I know that it has to be polynomial times that of `f(N)` which is `2^n` but I dont see how this is comparable with `2^n`.

I tried with recursion tree as well but it got too complicated.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the third case of the master theorem described [here](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno/CS424/Ressources/master.pdf) because f(n) is equal to Ω(nloga).

```
Here, 
f(n) = 2^n , and
Ω(n^log 1) = Ω(1)
```

`2^n = Ω(1)` , because for some constant c>0 and all large enough n, 2^n ≥ c*1.

So T(n) = f(n) 
T(n) = O(2^n)

Comment: I was mistaken, case 3 can be applied.

Comment: can you please help clear this confusion i have read that master theorem can only be applied when n^loga(b) can be expressed as n^loga(b)+^E or  n^loga(b)-^E where E is >0 otherwise its not applicable. But I dont seethat in your solution.

Comment: @aneenaTo be frank I don't remember any recurrence relation where the E factor came into play. I would recommend you to try some questions from the pdf I linked to and see if E is used anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy enough to do without the master theorem as well:

```
T(n) = T(n / 2) + 2^n)
     = T(n / 4) + 2^(n / 2) + 2^n
     = ...
     < 2^0 + 2^1 + ... + 2^n
     = [2^(n + 1) - 1] / (2 - 1) (sum of a geometric progression formula)

=> T(n) = O(2^(n + 1)) = O(2*2^n) = O(2^n)
```

Comment: I am unable to solve the following recurrence

T(n) = 3T(n/5) + lg^2 n

my work:
applying master theorem a=3 b=5
n^log5^3n= n^log^0.65   this leads to n^0=1 this isn't comparable with log^2n 
 
I tried with recursion tree as well but it got too complicated.please help

Comment: @aneena - that is another question entirely. Please start a different question for it, and make sure to show your work so it doesn't get closed.